# How to download entire front-end of a website

Tags: html, web

I want to download all the html, css and js files of the entire website in one click. I tried right-click and view source code but then I have to copy paste each page and create folder myself so its very tedious. Is there any open source software that helps do that or do i have to code it myself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`wget` is your friend here and it works on windows, mac and linux.

```
wget -r -np -k http://yourtarget.com/even/path/down/if/you/need/it/

-r is recursive
-np (do not follow links to parent directories)
-k to make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files
```

Other useful options:

```
-nd (no directories): download all files to the current directory
-e robots.off: ignore robots.txt files, do not download robots.txt files
-A png,jpg: accept only files with the extensions png or jpg
-m (mirror): -r --timestamping --level inf --no-remove-listing
```

Comment: wow linux is cool! problem is that im noob and still use windows. Any chrome extension or software for windows?

Comment: oh i got a way to use wget on windows! https://builtvisible.com/download-your-website-with-wget/

Comment: i have another question if you dont mind. If i can just download entire websites like this how do people protect "paid templates" as many of them give a demo ie live website. I can simply download it using wget without paying a dime. whats the catch here?

Comment: is there a db behind their demo? Is there an app layer that is doing something to render the html that you are seeing? This is going to pull what is used to render in your browser, not penetrate deep into the borg collective and steal all of their secrets.

Comment: if this works for you please mark as accepted. Makes it easier for others to find useful answers.

Answer (score -3):

Right Click > Save Page As

Will download all css and js/html.

Comment: This downloads only one page. The asker wants to download an entire website.