# How to get the source of a page that is reachable with the click of a button

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a script in python to download each day the pdfs that are published on a site.

I had no problem in scraping the page and downloading the files.
The problem that I'm facing currently is due to the fact that the site has more pages, I know what you are thinking ;) but it wouldn't be a problem if the site was structured like this:

```
page 1 -> www.example.com/page1
page 2 -> www.example.com/page2 ...
```

But the problem is that, unfortunately, when I press on the page number to change page

[image: pages]

nothing happens in the URL field.

The only thing I was able to find was this event in the console:

[image: console]

The page buttons I need to click are these:

```
<nav class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm files_paging"><li><a data-page="1" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li><li class="active"><a data-page="1">1</a></li><li><a data-page="2">2</a></li><li><a data-page="3">3</a></li><li><a data-page="4">4</a></li><li class="disabled"><a data-page="4"><span aria-hidden="true">...</span></a></li><li><a data-page="9">9</a></li><li><a data-page="2" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

Is there anyone who has got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the mentioned page uses a JavaScript framework for displaying the content. You should try the following options.

- Guess the pattern of the URLs.
- Download the frontend part of the page (HTML and JavaScript files) and search the point where the URLs have generated or retrieved.
- If you are interested in similar tasks you should try [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or an other similar browser based, programmable testing tool.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! "Guess the pattern of the URLs." Already tried, no success with that :(   "If you are interested in similar tasks you should try Selenium or an other similar browser based, programmable testing tool." I can't use a broswer. "Download the frontend part of the page (HTML and JavaScript files) and search the point where the URLs have generated or retrieved." Could you explain this with a bit more details?

Comment: You can use for example curl or wget as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750276/how-to-download-entire-front-end-of-a-website .

Comment: I am afraid wget will not work, even with the option - r because there is no link to follow